# optimize python code with basic libraries

Tags: python, loops, optimization

I'm trying to do a non equi self join with basic python on a table that has 1.7 millions rows and 4 variables.
the data look like this:

```
product     position_min     position_max      count_pos
A.16        167804              167870              20
A.18        167804              167838              15
A.15        167896              167768              18
A.20        238359              238361              33
A.35        167835              167837              8
```

here the code i used:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
import sys
import os

list_csv=[]
l=[]
with open(r'product.csv', 'r') as file1:
    my_reader1 = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=';')
    for row in my_reader1:
        list_csv.append(row)
with open(r'product.csv', 'r') as file2:
    my_reader2 = csv.reader(file2, delimiter=';') 
    with open('product_p.csv', "w") as csvfile_write:
        ecriture = csv.writer(csvfile_write, delimiter=';',
                                quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for row in my_reader2:
            res = defaultdict(list)
            for k in range(len(list_csv)):
                comp= list_csv[k]
                try:
                    if int(row[1]) >= int(comp[1]) and int(row[2]) <= int(comp[2]) and row[0] != comp[0]:
                        res[row[0]].append([comp[0],comp[3]]) 
                except:
                    pass
            


            if bool(res):    
                for key, value in res.items():
                    sublists = defaultdict(list)
                    for sublist in value:
                        l=[]
                        sublists[sublist[0]].append(int(sublist[1]))
                    l.append(str(key) + ";"+ str(min(sublists.keys(), key=(lambda k: sublists[k]))))
                        ecriture.writerow(l)
```

I should get this in the "product_p.csv" file:

```
'A.18'; 'A.16'
'A.15'; 'A.18'
'A.35'; 'A.18'
```

What the code does is to read the same file twice, the first time completely, and convert it into a list, and the 2nd time line by line and that is to find for each product (1st variable) all the products to which it belongs by the condition on position_min and position_max and after that choose only one by keeping the product that has the minimum of count_pos .

I tried it on a sample of the original data, it works, but with 1.7  millions rows, it runs for hours without giving any results.
Is there a way to dos that withour or with less loops ? could anyone help on optimizing this with basic python libraries ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please explain roughly, what your code is doing? I didn't understand  what your code is exactly doing!

Comment: @Kshitiz Thanks for your answer. What the code does is to read the same file twice, the first time completely, and convert it into a list, and the 2nd time line by line and that is to find for each product (1st variable) all the products to which it belongs by the condition on position_min and position_max and after that choose only one by keeping the product that has the minimum of count_pos .

Comment: Aren't you actually getting opposite you told that you want to get this `A16    A35` but you are actually getting `A35    A16` is it okay or not?

Comment: @Kshitiz, I corrected what I should get when compiling the code.

Comment: Now also I don't exactly understand what you are trying to do, but I had tried to do in `pandas` but the speed in pandas is worse the your code also. I had tested with 2000 dataset but your code is fast enough then mine. If I had understood exactly what you are doing then I may try other approaches also! And I have noticed in your code that you don't have to read that file 2 times for exact same data, you may use previous data in second. I didn't check if that makes your code faster or not but I noticed that

Comment: I can't use pandas, but just basic python libraries. i tried reading the file once, but it didn't work in the loop when i want to read it row by row. I don't know if there is a way to do what the code is doing without or with less loops, have you any ideas?

Comment: It is possible to read the file just once, since you already have all the necessary data stored in `list_csv`. You can't iterate again through `my_reader1` because it is a sort of generator and after reading it, you'd need to make operations on it to get back to the initial position. But it is not needed as you can go through `list_csv`, item by item.

Comment: @MatBBastos Thank you for response. reading the file only once doesn't speed up it's running . There are sevral nested loops, have you an idea how to do the same thing with itertools library or anything else ?

Comment: I believe the code can be a bit simpler, but I don't think you can escape so many comparisons. You need to compare each row with each other row, at least, in order to know the correct output for that specific product. Still, about 2 million rows shouldn't be much of a problem as to not give output after hours.

Comment: Does this come from a database? Any chance you can create a solution in SQL? SQL is designed to manage sets of data like this and this kind of logic would be pretty trivial to do in SQL

Comment: The end  of the code is suspiciously bogus: `l=[]` is inside the for loop while `l.append` is outside the loop which is very surprising to me (why the operation is repeated and what is the rational ? not to mention the initial `l=[]` at the beginning). Are you sure this part of the code is correct? Did you check the results on a smaller dataset?

Answer (score 3):

I think a different approach is needed here, because comparing each product with each other will always give a time complexity of O(n^2).

I sorted the product list by ascending `position_min` (and descending `position_max`, just in case) and reversed the check from the answer above: instead of seeing if `comp` "contains" `ref` I did the opposite. This way it is possible to check each product only against those with a higher `position_min`, and also to stop the search as soon as a `comp` is found whose `position_min` is higher than `position_max` of `ref`.

To test this solution I generated a random list of 100 products and run both one function copied from the answer above, and one function based on my suggestion. The latter executes about 1000 comparisons instead of 10000, and according to `timeit` it is about 4x faster despite the overhead due to the initial sort.

Code follows:

```
##reference function
def f1(basedata):
    outd={}
    for ref in basedata:
        for comp in basedata:
            if ref == comp:
                continue
            elif ref[1] >= comp[1] and ref[2] <= comp[2]:
                if not outd.get(ref[0], False) or comp[3] < outd[ref[0]][1]:
                    outd[ref[0]] = (comp[0], comp[3])
    return outd

##optimized(?) function
def f2(basedata):
    outd={}
    sorteddata = sorted(basedata, key=lambda x:(x[1],-x[2]))
    runs = 0
    for i,ref in enumerate(sorteddata):
        toohigh=False
        j=i
        while j < len(sorteddata)-1 and not toohigh:
            j+=1
            runs+=1
            comp=sorteddata[j]
            if comp[1] > ref[2]:
                toohigh=True
            elif comp[2] <= ref[2]:
                if not outd.get(comp[0], False) or ref[3] < outd[comp[0]][1]:
                    outd[comp[0]] = (ref[0], ref[3])
    print(runs)
    return outd
```

Comment: Neat. Great idea to sort data beforehand. For small cases, shouldn't make much of a difference, but since OP talks about millions of rows, this is really relevant. A thing that stuck with me, maybe only for the sake of completeness: we'd still need the `int` conversion after reading from the `csv`, right?

Comment: Yes, the conversion is required in a real application. I generated the values with `randint` for my test so I didn't need it

Answer (score 1):

I removed some libraries that were not used and tried to simplify the behavior of the code as much as I could.

The most important objects in the code are the list `input_data`, that stores data from the input `csv` file and the dict `out_dict`, that stores the output of the comparisons.

Simply put, what the code does is:

1. Reads `product.csv` (without headers) into a list `input_data`
2. Iterates through `input_data` comparing each row to each **other** row

   - If the reference product range is *within* the comparing product range, we check a new condition: is there something in `out_dict` for the reference product?

     - If yes, we replace it with the new comparing product **if** it has a lower `count_pos`
     - If not, we add the comparing product regardless
3. Writes the information in `out_dict` to the output file `product_p.csv`, but only for products that had valid comparing products

And here it is:

```py
import csv

input_data = []
with open('product.csv', 'r') as csv_in:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_in, delimiter=';')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        input_data.append(row)


out_dict = {}
for ref in input_data:
    for comp in input_data:
        if ref == comp:
            continue
        elif int(ref[1]) >= int(comp[1]) and int(ref[2]) <= int(comp[2]):
            if not out_dict.get(ref[0], False) or int(comp[3]) < out_dict[ref[0]][1]:
                out_dict[ref[0]] = (comp[0], int(comp[3]))
                # print(f"In '{ref[0]}': placed '{comp[0]}'")


with open('product_p.csv', "w") as csv_out:
    ecriture = csv.writer(csv_out, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for key, value in out_dict.items():
        if value[0]:
            ecriture.writerow([key, value[0]])
```

Also, I commented out a `print` line that can show you - using a sample file with only a few rows - what the script is doing.

---

Note:
I believe your expected output is wrong. Either that or I'm missing something from the explanation. If that's the case, do tell me. The code presented takes this into account.

From the sample input:

```
product;position_min;position_max;count_pos
A.16;167804;167870;20
A.18;167804;167838;15
A.15;167896;167768;18
A.20;238359;238361;33
A.35;167835;167837;8
```

The expected output would be:

```
"A.18";"A.16"
"A.15";"A.35"
"A.35";"A.18"
```

Since, for "A.15", "A.35" satisfies the same conditions as "A.16" and "A.18" **and** has the smaller `count_pos`.

Comment: Just updated the answer since there is no real need, as I see, to use `defaultdict`, a simple `get` for the key suffices. To create keys using `[]` notation, there's no need to already have a default value. Also, just `out_dict.get(ref[0])` would be enough - since it would return `None`, which is boolean `False` - though not the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Using sqlite3 in-memory database the search can be moved to B-tree indexes that is more optimal than suggested ways. The following approach works 30 times faster that the original one. For generated 2M rows file it takes 44 hours to calculate result for each item (~1200 hours for original approach).

```
import csv
import sqlite3
import sys
import time

with sqlite3.connect(':memory:') as con:
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE products (id integer PRIMARY KEY, product text, position_min int, position_max int, count_pos int)')
    cursor.execute('CREATE INDEX idx_products_main ON products(position_max, position_min, count_pos)')

    with open('product.csv', 'r') as products_file:
        reader = csv.reader(products_file, delimiter=';')
        # Omit parsing first row in file
        next(reader)

        for row in reader:
            row_id = row[0][len('A.'):] if row[0].startswith('A.') else row[0];
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO products VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [row_id] + row)

    con.commit()

    with open('product_p.csv', 'wb') as write_file:
        with open('product.csv', 'r') as products_file:
            reader = csv.reader(products_file, delimiter=';')
            # Omit parsing first row in file
            next(reader)

            for row in reader:
                row_product_id, row_position_min, row_position_max, count_pos = row
                result_row = cursor.execute(
                    'SELECT product, count_pos FROM products WHERE position_min <= ? AND position_max >= ? ORDER BY count_pos, id LIMIT 1',
                    (row_position_min, row_position_max)
                ).fetchone()

                if (result_row and result_row[0] == row_product_id):
                    result_row = cursor.execute(
                        'SELECT product, count_pos FROM products WHERE product != ? AND position_min <= ? AND position_max >= ? ORDER BY count_pos, id LIMIT 1',
                        (row_product_id, row_position_min, row_position_max)
                    ).fetchone()

                if (result_row):
                    write_file.write(f'{row_product_id};{result_row[0]};{result_row[1]}\n'.encode())
```

Further  optimisation can be done using threading if needed and the result process can be optimised to take 4-5 hours using 10 threads for instance.